# Changing all functions that returns Promise to observable

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I have an API where nearly every function returns a Promise. I want to use this API in a reactive way. For a single case it looks like this:

```
source.pipe(
    mergeMap(action => {
        return defer<[]>(() => API.callThatReturnsAPromise()).pipe(
            map(result => {
                return doFancyStuff(result);
            })
        );
    })
)
```

Assume there are a lot of those functions that return a promise ( some with args, others not).

**Is there an elegant way to make those promises to observables without the manualy wrap with defer and handing the possible arguments?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use from

```
source.pipe(
  mergeMap(action => from(API.callThatReturnsAPromise())),
  map(result => doFancyStuff(result))
)
```

from takes a promises as an input and returns an observable.

```js
const { of, from, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { mergeMap, map } = rxjs.operators;

let source$ = fromEvent(document.getElementById('source'), 'click');

let API = {
  callThatReturnsAPromise: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('resolving');
    resolve('done');
  })
};

const doFancyStuff = val => `Result of promise was: ${val}`;

source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => from(API.callThatReturnsAPromise())),
  map(result => doFancyStuff(result))
).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="source">Click</button>
```

Comment: With from the promise is already executing before any handlers have been connected. i wont this behavior.

Comment: The promise is executing when it is created. The mergeMap does not fire until the source emits. See my runnable snippet I have added. The observable chain can be set up without creating a promise until you click the button which makes the source emit.

Comment: Calling API.callThatReturnsAPromise() runs the promise, so does from(API.callThatReturnsAPromise()), how else can you wrap a promise without creating it? The mergeMap function does not create the wrapped promise observable until the source emits which is exactly the same behaviour as your question so it is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 0):

Your question almost has the answer in it.

```
const toObservable=(promiseFn,mapFn)=>
       defer<[]>(() => promiseFn()).pipe(
            map(result => {
                return mapFn(result);
            })
        );


// usage
   api.get=()=>Promise.resolve('ok')
   mapFn=(value)=>...your map logic
   toObservable(api.get,mapFn).subscribe()
```

Comment: Or you could just use from